# Electronic test clip (hook/grabber): how to open it up?

Tags: testing

How do I properly disassemble one of these hooked test clips? The wire broke off: you can see the tiny remainder inside the oval hole. I want to fix / re-solder the wire, but how do I open up the plastic tube enclosure to get to the inside? I see copper/plastic moving parts inside, but no obvious way (like a paperclip hole etc) to unlock the mechanism.

[image: Hook clip 1]
[image: Hook clip 2]

Comment: That looks like an oscilloscope probe, you might have some luck on the Electronics stack site.

Comment: OK, thanks, I didn't know there was one for electronics

Comment: Grab the smaller moving part with one hand (left side in the picture), and the right side plastic hooky part with the other hand, and pull.

Comment: I'll try. I was reluctant to do this, because I thought I may break something inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the smaller moving part with one hand (left side in the picture), and the right side plastic hooky part with the other hand, and pull.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was reluctant to pull anything by force, so I don't break something inside